# Firebase Mixing Versions

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

i had added those libraries to my code

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
```

then i found an error in that line

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```

saying there is a **Mixing versions problem**

Comment: @Mamoud Gamal update to 27.1.1 and check you are using the latest version of google services

Answer (score 0):

try to add all same version of firebase apis:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
```

change:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
```

maybe it should help.

Comment: After version 15, the same version of Firebase dependencies are no longer required.  They can now change independently.

Answer (score 0):

Your firebase dependencies is updated so first of all update your build tool version if you dont:

```
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

And replace 27.0.2 to:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

(also make sure that every single library is updated) [based on this link for the latest varsion](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#fixed-issues)

Make sure that your gradle file is like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        //..
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        //..
    }
}
```